# Importar dados do Excel para uma ListBox do Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net

Quero uma ajuda no problem do título... Eu sei que posso fazer essa importação pelo VBA, mas quero que meu programa detecte o formato .xls de uma planilha e extraia seus dados para uma ListBox dentro do Visual Studio.

Tem como?

Comment: Você pode usar a interoperabilidade do excel, assim você lê o arquivo .xls e pega as informações que precisa.

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo em C#  -> http://www.dontbreakthebuild.com/2011/01/30/excel-and-c-interop-with-net-4-how-to-read-data-from-excel/

Comment: Isso também funciona para o Access?

Comment: Se o Access tiver interop..

Answer (score 2):

Se você não tiver medo de trabalhar "no escuro", isto é, sem ajuda do intellisense e da detecção de erros do Visual Studio, pode referenciar a aplicação Excel como *Object* e usar os mesmos métodos que usaria em VBA. Isto se chama *[Late Binding](http://www.macoratti.net/vbbind.htm)*.

O Código abaixo, por exemplo, tenta se apropriar de uma instância do Excel que já esteja em execução (com **GetObject()**). Se não houver, o erro é tratado com a criação de uma nova instância (com **CreateObject()**).

A partir daí, estamos em terreno familiar. Abre-se a pasta de trabalho localizada em "C:\Users\Fulano\Desktop\Planilha.xls" e percorrem-se as células da faixa "A1:A10" da planilha "Plan1". Os valores são copiados para uma List(Of String) onde ficarão disponíveis para você usar como quiser:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Excel As Object
    Try
        Excel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End Try
    Excel.Visible = True
    Dim WorkBook As Object = Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Fulano\Desktop\Planilha.xls")
    Dim WorkSheet As Object = WorkBook.Worksheets("Plan1")
    Dim MyList As New List(Of String)
    Dim Range = WorkSheet.Range("A1:A10")
    For Each Cell In Range.Cells
        MyList.Add(Cell.Value)
    Next
    WorkBook.Close
    Excel.Quit
    Excel = Nothing
    Stop
End Sub
```

Espero que isso ajude.